# SSIS package last date run

Tags: date

I have a single step job that executes a query that extract data to put in a xls file.

I would like get the date of the last successful job execution time so that I can just update a delta instead of the whole set of data.

Right now I have the job setup to run once every day, but I want to schedule it every 5 minutes (from SQL server agent).

In the job query I select a field called 'update date' (from the source database) and this date must be compared to the 'last run date' of the job in SSIS. In this way if a table row update date is greater (consecutive) than the last run date I select the row to export.

How can I select the last run date (both cases: success and failure)? I must query the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table in a Execute Sql task? The last run date must be stored in a single row variable and then compared in the query that extract the delta? Any idea or tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something similar and decided to give a heads up on the links that assisted me:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=112427
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic542581-145-1.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.